# openGL: How to disable pixel interpolation on dds textures

Tags: opengl, textures

I use textures to pass huge amount of datas to my vertex shader, and it works (the point is to convert each rgba pixel into a 32 bit float). the thing is that recently, I tried to use dds format instead of jpg (much faster to load). It works for all my colors / normals textures (just had to vertically invert images), but it causes all my data maps to bug. I tryed several things, like disabling alphas, which work on jpg but not on dds. I think this is caused by pixel interpolation which seems to be different between jpg/png/bmp and dds.

Is there a way to disable that interpolation?

If the problem isn't interpolation, do you know what could it be?

Comment: Unless you show some code, it's impossible to tell whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but showing code is pretty difficult for this. My point is just to know if I'm right when i think that pixel interpolation is different between jpg and dds, and if that's right, how to disable it.

Comment: Image formats don't define interpolation, only sampler parameters do. Also if you rely on lossy DXT compression (as I understood you do) for 'data maps' (what are they?), it's normal to get inaccurate/wrong values.

Comment: Thanks I effectively use DXT compression, so the problem might come from here. Didn't no that's a lossy one. I use those data maps to apply morphs on my bodies. One pixel = one vertex coordinate modification. Thanks again for that helpfull reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like pleluron said, my dds textures uses DXT compression, wich leads to a quality loss. That coupled with RGBA to float decoding results in wrong datas. Interpolation isn't the problem here.

Comment: Also use `texelFetch()` in your shader so the data doesn't get interpolated.

Comment: Don't know that, function, I'll look at it. Thanks a lot!